# 3-D printing of formulas encoded in LaTex for the visually impaired?

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, secondary-education, specific-software, special-needs-education

There is software available on the Net for 3-D printing of math expressions encoded in LaTex. What such technology is available off-the-shelf for the visually impaired to learn mathematics? And, accompanying research/anecdotes on its effectiveness?

Comment: On assistive technology for education in general: http://www.edutopia.org/blog/film-festival-assistive-technology,  https://nfb.org/technology-resource-list

Comment: I'm trying to understand, when you ask about "what such technology", how closely related to 3D-printed formulas you're looking for the answers to fall.  Are you interested specifically in 3D-printed formulas, or in printing other objects in lieu of visualizations, or are you talking about haptic learning aids in general?

Comment: @forritari:  I meant to target the question for 3-D printing of mathematical expressions for the blind, but if you can link to other AT for learning math for the visually impaired, please do (reconfigurable pins, e.g.). (Would make a great project for  team of math/engineering/CS majors.) It would also be beneficial to understand the differences in effectiveness of haptic aids and aural aids.

Comment: For problems in planar geometry, one blind student I knew of used rubber bands and pins on a board to assist her understanding.

Comment: Related: https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/teaching-blind-students-with-3-d-prints/, https://www.thevalleyacademy.net/apps/pages/index.jsp?uREC_ID=770193&type=u&pREC_ID=1310435

Comment: https://www.thevalleyacademy.net/apps/pages/index.jsp?uREC_ID=770193&type=u&pREC_ID=1305710

Comment: Related AT: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430329/is-there-a-reasonable-text-to-speech-solution-for-math-papers